# How do I perform this query without relying on looping in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, inner-join

I'm brand new with MySQL.  It appears like I need to do some sort of loop in a MySQL request, but I think it could be way more efficient with some "INNER JOIN" stuff.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$query = 'SELECT id FROM membres WHERE pseudo = :pseudo LIMIT 1';
$req = $dtb -> prepare($query);
$req -> execute(array(
    'pseudo' => $_COOKIE['pseudo']
));
while($donnes = $req -> fetch()){
    $id_pseudo = $donnes['id'];
}
$req -> closeCursor();
$query = 'SELECT id_chanson FROM samples WHERE id_membre = :id_pseudo';
$req = $dtb -> prepare($query);
$req -> execute(array(
    'id_pseudo' => $id_pseudo
));
$id_chansons = array();
while($donnes = $req -> fetch()){
    $id_chansons[] = $donnes['id_chanson'];
}
$req->closeCursor();
$nSongs= count($id_chansons);
$query = 'SELECT nom, pathName, date FROM chansons WHERE id = :id_chanson';
$req = $dtb -> prepare($query);
for($i=0;$i<$nSongs;$i++){
    $req -> execute(array(
        'id_chanson' => $id_chansons[$i]
    ));
    while($donnes = $req -> fetch()){
        $nomChanson[$i] = $donnes['nom'];
        $pathName[$i] = $donnes['pathName'];
        $date[$i] = $donnes['date'];
    }
}
```

EDIT: my table names are "chansons" (songs in french) "membres" (users) and "samples"

:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for formatting your code.  It would help if you talk about the SQL query you want to do, and the table structures.  You're looping in PHP rather than in MySQL.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit ... does it still say what you are looking for?

Comment: yes! this is perfect!! :) ty for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it's often much more efficient to run a single query rather than multiple queries. It's faster on the database (fewer round trips), and it makes for much friendlier code.

Here's an example SQL query that will retrieve the rows from `chansons`:

```
    SELECT c.nom
         , c.pathName
         , c.date
      FROM (SELECT id FROM membres WHERE pseudo = :pseudo ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) m
      JOIN samples s 
        ON s.id_membre = m.id
      JOIN chansons c
        ON c.id = s.id_chanson
     ORDER BY 1
```

NOTES:

If you need the id values from the other tables returned in the result set, expressions for those can be included in the SELECT list as well.  (From your code, I don't see that those id values being used for anything other than a subsequent query... but of course that doesn't mean they aren't referenced elsewhere.

I added an ORDER BY to the query in the inline view, to make it deterministic. If there is more than one row that satisfies the query, absent an ORDER BY clause, it is arbitrary which row will be returned by MySQL, that is, the result returned from a subsequent execution is not guaranteed to be the same as the previous run.)

The query above makes use of an inline view (MySQL calls it a derived table) aliased as `m`, to get the `LIMIT 1` on the number of rows returned from `membres`.  If you don't need that LIMIT, then the query can be simplified by removing that inline view.

The `INNER` keyword is optional, it has no influence on the optimizer. That is, `INNER JOIN` is synonymous with `JOIN`.

Comment: YEAAAAAAAH PARTY :) 
That is nice!!!! That query gave me headache even if it was not such a big deal I'm so grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id, s.id_chanson, ch.nom, ch.pathName, ch.date
  from membres m
       inner join samples s on m.id = s.id_membre
       inner join chansons ch on s.id_chanson = ch.id
 where pseudo = :pseudo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let's try this!